# Select Records With Multiple Specific Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to make a SQL query where I can find all ids of a member (member_ids) with all branches.

This all branches is an array consisting of all branch ids. So for example the values of all branches is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

I want to query similar to this one:

```
SELECT member_id FROM member_branch WHERE branch_id IN [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

But to query all member_id having all branch_id. Because if a member_id has only `[1,2,3]`, it will be included also in the query, and I don't want.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: 2017.140.1000.169

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
 Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected results?

Comment: Please post in details with example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT member_id FROM member_branch where branch_id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly and based on the format of the data in the `branch_id` column ( which is a valid JSON array), you may try to use a JSON-based approach. When you parse a JSON array (`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` for example) using `OPENJSON()` and default schema, the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`. After that,  you may use any set-base approach (`EXCEPT` and `OUTER APPLY` in the example).

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE member_branch (
   member_id int,
   branch_id nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO member_branch 
   (member_id, branch_id)
VALUES
   (1, '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]'),
   (2, '[1,2,3,4]'),
   (3, '[10]'),
   (4, '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]')
DECLARE @branches nvarchar(100) = N'[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT m.member_id
FROM member_branch m
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT [value] FROM OPENJSON(@branches)
   EXCEPT
   SELECT [value] FROM OPENJSON(m.branch_id)
) j
WHERE j.[value] IS NULL
```

Result:

```
---------
member_id
---------
1
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this not work.

```
declare @branchCount int =10
select member_id from (SELECT member_id, branch_id  FROM member_branch WHERE branch_id IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')) a group by a.member_id having count(a.member_id)>=@branchCount
```